# I have a problem with loading data to Textview.Binding.tvTimecount.text doesn't show when I run project

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

binding.tvTimecount.text doesn't show when I run this project

```kotlin
private fun loadTimer() {
    var string: String?
    istimerunning = true
    timer.schedule(
        object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                timecount ++
                val second = timecount % 60
                val hour = timecount / 3600
                val minut = (timecount - hour*3600)/60
                string = String.format("%2d:%2d:%2d",hour,minut,second)
                binding.tvTimecount.text = string
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and add some more explanaiton to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Your timer code executes in the background thread so you need to write set text view code in main thread because the background thread can't touch views

Simply cover set text code with runOnUiThread{} as below

```
runOnUiThread {

binding.tvTimecount.text = string

}
```